# AD Saml login with an OAuth 2 protected webapi?

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml

Need some help understanding this, we have a webapi protected with AAD OAuth 2 token using OWIN middleware. Now the vendor is asking to use SAML for authenticate and OAuth for authorization,'OAuth is supported for API calls but it uses SAML for app login', very confused by this and not know where to look for references for configuration and if any change to the existing API, could someone please help with some pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details about your scenario, like what kind of app are you considering? Please note that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find step by step instructions about this, as SAML isn't really designed to handle web API scenario. Please also note that
- We have no middleware supporting the SAML protocol out of the box. Do you mean SAML tokens and WS-Fed protocol perhaps?
- SAML and WS-Fed describe apps as *resources*, but in order to call an API you need a *client*; that means that you would need to use two different set of config coordinates for the app, the SAML/WS-Fed one for auth and the OAuth2 one for the call. You might be able to make this work with Azure AD (as the session cookie issued at sign in time is the same regardless of the web sso protocol) but it will require extra configuration - and per the above, there won't be documentation helping you to stitch the flows together

Comment: Thanks this sounds about align to what we hear from our vendor, the way we understand is they want to do saml authenication the use the token in response to exchange for access token, if I am understanding this flow correctly does it mean there is no change to my webapi code which is currently use oauth? Another question not sure if the access token referring here is a jwt or saml one so I can pull the user claim from, still confuse a bit, I thought saml and oauth are mutually exclusive it seems they can use together in this case..

Comment: @TOMMYWANG do you know what identity provider are they using? If it's Azure ad, they will not be able to exchange a saml token for a jwt for your web API. They can stitch a saml sso with an authorization code grant, which is what I described earlier.

Comment: It is actually azure ad as idp per vendor explanation, could you please elaborate (or better yet point me to some readings) on how to handle this in my webapi?

Comment: @TOMMYWANG your web API should not require any changes. It's their client that needs to adapt, and as I mentioned there is nothing i can point them to as it is a scenario that is usually handled differently (opened connect)

Comment: Thanks so assuming owing API will give me the claim data as usual, from my webapi perspective still oauth then? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: That's what you should require them to do, yes. But as I mentioned earlier, it won't be easy for them to comply.